# VHDL Multi-Process

Tags: synchronization, vhdl

I have a problem in synchronize my code .First I tried to put All my functions in one process but to check an instruction to another it will take an additional cycle and I didn't want this to be happened so I Put every instruction in a process so all functions could be processed in the same cycle .But I found a problem on using a multi process and do an operation in a variable it will give me "xxxx" value to this variable despite I didn't use them in the same cycle

```
 Process ( T )
  begin
      If ( T(0)='1' )Then
          AR <= PC;
      End If ; 
end process;
process ( T )
begin
      If ( T(1)='1' )Then
          IR<=Data;
          PC<=PC+1;
      End If ;
End process;
process ( T )
begin
      If ( T(2)='1' )Then
          I<=IR(15);
          AR<=IR( 11 downto 0 );
      End If ;
End Process ;
```

this code is running well in case of t(0) and t(1) but in  case of t(2) AR vale is "xxxx".

why in t(2) give me this value ??

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.2 Drivers "Every signal assignment statement in a process statement defines a set of drivers for certain scalar signals." 14.7.3.2 Driving values "  14.7.3.2 Driving values "If S is a resolved signal and has one or more sources, then the driving values of the sources of S are examined." ..."...the driving value of S is obtained by executing the resolution function associated with S, where that function is called with an input parameter consisting of the concatenation of the driving values of the sources of S,...."  What is the type of AR?

Comment: 4.6 Resolution functions "A resolution function is a function that defines how the values of multiple sources of a given signal are to be resolved into a single value for that signal. Resolution functions are associated with signals that require resolution by including the name of the resolution function in the declaration of the signal or in the declaration of the subtype of the signal." For std_logic_vector the latter  is function resolved in IEEE package std_logic_1164. In package body you'll find a resolution table used to resolve multiple drivers two values  at a time. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say but there is so much wrong here I don't know where to start.

Let's begin with stating that you have provided only a tiny snippet of code. For better assessment you should provide the full code plus test-bench. So I have to do some guessing here and there.

Next, there are no 'cycles' here as there is no clock. You just have a set of three processes. If you really want to have 'cycles' you should add a clock and work with clock edges (there are lots of examples out there).

Then: the processes do not have the correct sensitivity list. You only use T : `Process ( T )`. Any changes in `data` or `Ir` or `PC` are ignored. Your code might simulate but it will not match what the hardware does.

As to "t(2) AR vale is 'xxxx'." You have two processes changing AR.That is a race condition. You don't know which of the two is going to win (and your synthesis tool will refuse to build logic for this). I would also expect your VHDL simulator to complain about that. Did you do something to circumvent that?

To fix some if this stop writing as if VHDL is a standard sequential programming language. In HDL *everything* is happening/changing *at the same time* and your code should be able to cope with that.
For example: your T has at least three 'bits'? Maybe more or different values, but we can't see that as you have omitted the definitions. Thus your T can have *eight!* values.

Put all your code in one process with the right sensitivity list and work through the *eight* combinations of T. Decide what the outcome should be in each of the eight case case.

I repeat myself: the above is my best guess of what you need, there is a lot of information missing .